# Building a wordcloud around an element in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I need to create a word cloud that looks like the following, [image: Wordcloud with HTML element in between]

The bordered element is a button, and the elements around are supposed to be a wordcloud.

I have been able to use a [react-wordcloud](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-wordcloud) library for the just the word cloud but putting an element in between has left me in a fix.

One method I can think of is using an div as overlay, but the clear downside I can think is that I will have no control over the what will lie beneath the button.

I am out of ideas as in how to achieve this, and any help will be appreciable

Comment: Hello, if i need to solve this i'll create multiple divs with css `z-index` property and `position: absolute`. Also i'll use `transform: translateX(Y)` props and some JS to calc positions

Comment: you can test for overlap and move stuff after render--perhaps animate it if appropriate.  another option is to use a force-directed graph for the words.  lots of work in any solution i'm afraid but definitely do-able.